# Why am I unable to post a request to a server which allows request from all origin with fetch or axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to send an http request to an endpoint to no avail. If I change the method to GET , it comes back with a response, but with POST method, it fails to fetch. The endpoint is https://mtstorez.000webhostapp.com/app/store/login. I have used fetch, axios still the same result.

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I have tried using axios and fetch still the same result.  I have configured the back end to accept request from all origin still no results.

However I tried testing the endpoint  with online tool and it went through

Comment: Your browser "Network" developer tool will allow you to inspect the HTTP response headers to verify that the CORS headers are correctly configured. (If the browser is giving you an error, that means they are probably not.)

Comment: When I try that URL, I see no CORS headers.

Comment: If GET works but POST doesn't then I would assume the remote resource is secured by `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET`, which will disallow the POST. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) for more info on this. The documentation of the API should detail which HTTP verbs are enabled for each endpoint.

Comment: Make sure the server-side endpoint is configured to accept HTTP POST requests. It's possible that the endpoint only accepts GET requests or that it requires additional authentication or parameters to accept POST requests.